# Choice between a hierarchical sub-collection and two collections

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In a traditional JSON architecture, a chat room might be organised as follows:

```
{
    "chatrooms" : {
        "room1" : {
            "room_owner" : "andy_cap",
            "room_name" : "cartoon_strips"
        },
        "room2" : {
            ...
        }
    },
    "chats" : {
        "chat1" : {
            "speaker" : "...",
            "text" : "...",
            "room" : "room1"
        },
        "chat2" : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The Firestore architecture is different however and recommends according to the [documentation from Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model?authuser=0) to embed chats as sub-collections in the chatrooms.

```
let messageRef = db
    .collection("rooms").document("roomA")
    .collection("messages").document("message1")
```

Choosing for Firestore has a lot of pros and cons compared to the older Firebase Realtime database option, but the collection/sub-collection architecture potentially means latency and pricing issues.  It appears a query of a chatroom will result in a download of the complete set of chats in that room, which is not really something that is wanted when setting up chatrooms for a user to choose from.

```
let docRef = db.collection("rooms").document("roomA")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Has someone a suggestion for how to manage this hierarchy?  Is there a way for example to only download chatroom data (owner, name, etc.) in Firestore and use a deeper query if a user chooses to enter it and read the chats?

Comment: There is no way to read partial documents, nor to do a deep-read (that also reads subcollections). If you need to reduce the number of calls, store the data you need in a specific document.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that's clear.  In short, the best approach is to store chats in a separate collection and not in a sub-collection of the chatroom.

Comment: I'm not sure what lead you to that conclusion. I also just noticed this in your question: ""It appears a query of a chatroom will result in a download of the complete set of chats in that room." If the chats are in a subcollection under the room, that is precisely **not** the case. Queries on Firestore are shallow, unlike queries on Realtime Database.

Comment: After I’d pressed send, I was asking myself the same question. I wasn’t trying to read a partial document, just assuming that downloading a document brought all sub-collections with it. I started to think about how deleting a document does not delete its sub-collections,. The implication is that the sub-collection is within a path that includes the document above it, but from the perspective of read, write (and delete) is a completely separate entity. The correct conclusion therefore is downloading a document does not lead to downloading its sub-collections.